# To what extent is duplicate code OK in a model with CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

This is a long running question that gets me every time I am developing.

I suppose it is not specific to CodeIgniter, but as I am using it, I will consider it in my example.

Firstly, which is better:

```
function add_entry($data_array)
{
    //code to add entry
}

function edit_entry($data_array)
{
    //code to update entry
}
```

OR

```
function save_changes($what,$data_array)
{
    //if what == update update
    //otherwise insert
}
```

Both produce the same action, but does it really matter which one you use?

Getting onto more complicated things.

I have a page where I need to get ONE entry from the database.

I also have a page where I need to get all the entries from the same database ordered by a user specified column.

My resultant method is a function similar to

```
function($data_array,$order_by='',$limit='')
{
    //get where $data_array
    //if order_by!='' add order by 
    //if limit !='' add limit
}
```

As I develop my application and realise new places where I need 'similar' database functionality I am what feels like hacking previous methods so they work with all my case scenarios. The methods end up containing lots of conditional statements, and getting quite complex with in some cases 4 or 5 input parameters.

Have I missed the point? I don't want duplicate code, and when for the most part the functions are very similar I feel like this 'hacking' methodology works best.

Could someone advise?

Finally my admin functionality is part of the same application in an admin controller. I have an admin model which contains specific methods for admin db interaction. I however use some model functionality from 'user' models.

FOr example if on an admin page I need to get details of a db entry I may load the user model to access this function. There is nothing wrong/insecure about this..? right?

In addition to that within my admin model itself I need to get data about a user database entry so I call my user model directly from my admin model. This is strictly OK, but why? If i need data and there is already a method in my user model which gets it.. it seems a little pointless to rewrite the code in the admin model BUT each time that function is called does it load the whole user model again?

Thanks a lot all.

Comment: As always: Don't repeat yourself! Why not put your functions in your models' base class or a generic DAO?

Answer (score 1):

In order, add edit in the model vs save. Personally I have a save built in MY_Model that chooses whether it is a save or an edit depending on the existence of a primary key in the data being passed, so obviously I prefer that method it means a lot less duplication of code since I can use the save for any table without having functions in the model at all.

As to the second question I think it depends on situation. I also have a number of functions that have a ton of conditionals on them depending on where they're used and for what. In some cases I'm finding this makes the legibility of the code a little rough. If you're running them all through if statements it also could be impacting performance. DRY is a concept, not a rule and like other design concepts there are times when they just don't make sense, it's like database normalization, it's my personal opinion it's VERY easy to over normalize a database and destroy performance and usability.

Finally, using user functions in the admin code. I don't see an issue here at all, the reverse probably isn't true, but rewriting a function just because it's an "admin" function, when it's identical to a user function is utterly pointless. So you're correct there, it's a waste of time and space.